# Create a SQL column based on list of values

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a column dependent on whether a certain value exists in a list regardless of when it occurs.

In my table currently I have:

- Attendee No - unique number for every attendance Tracking Activity -
- Description of Activity Tracking Date/Time - Date & Time when
- Activity took place Activity Type - <<<< I need to calculate this
  column based on specific logic

> [Attendee No] can have multiple [Tracking Activity] & associated [Tracking Date/Time]

Table example. **Tracker**

```
    +-------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------+
    | Attendee_No | Tracking Activity | Tracking Date/Time | Activity Type |
    +-------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------+
    |        3623 | Eat              | 05/04/2020 16:28   | Physical       |
    |        3623 | Music            | 05/04/2020 07:16   | Physical       |
    |        3623 | Run              | 05/04/2020 03:52   | Physical       |
    |        3623 | Booked in        | 05/04/2020 03:42   | Physical       |
    |        3624 | Sleep            | 05/04/2020 15:47   | Physical       |
    |        3624 | Walk             | 05/04/2020 11:55   | Physical       |
    |        3624 | TV               | 05/04/2020 11:54   | Physical       |
    |        3624 | Booked in        | 05/04/2020 11:52   | Physical       |
    +-------------+------------------+--------------------+----------------+
```

Using the example above what im looking to do is:

For every **Attendee No** if the **Tracker Activity** = "Run", "Walk", "Jog", "Gym" regardless when it occurred the **Activity Type** should = "Physical"

im a SQL noob so have no idea what im doing really so your help will be SOOOO GRATEFULLY appreciated!

Comment: Please tag your DBMS. Add your expected output, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For every Attendee No if the Tracker Activity = "Run", "Walk", "Jog", "Gym" regardless when it occurred the Activity Type should = "Physical"

```
   SELECT 
     CASE 
       WHEN activity IN('Run','Walk','Jog','Gym') THEN 'Physical'
       --WHEN .... other boolean test .. THEN ... other output value...
       --ELSE .. catch all value...
     END as ActivityType
   FROM
     ...
```

The -- is commented out - i put these things in as comments to show you how to add more cases, and how to add an else. If you want to use them, uncomment them and modify them.

CASE WHEN has to perform X number of tests and return a single value. It cannot return multiple values

CASE WHEN can also be written like:

```
   CASE activity
     WHEN 'Walk' THEN 'Physical'
     WHEN 'Jog' THEN 'Physical'
     ...
     --ELSE ...
```

In this format, you can only supply a single value after the WHEN, and it is compared using `=`. You can't `CASE column WHEN > 0 THEN..` or `CASE column WHEN value AND othercolumn = blah THEN..`

If you want those kinds of complexity you have to use the `CASE WHEN column > 0 AND othercolumn = blah THEN..` form

---

If you get lots of variations, or you expect to be able to add more in the future without modifying the sql, create another table that has two columns:

```
Activity,ActivityType
------------
Run,Physical
Walk,Physical
Jog,Physical
Gym,Physical
Study,Mental 
...
```

And join it in:

```
SELECT * FROM
  table t
  INNER JOIN activityTypes a ON a.Activity = t.Activity
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can have a CASE logic to calculate the Activity Type.

> As a general best practice, when you are naming the columns, avoid
>   below things. They will lead to issues one or other way.
>
> - Names with spaces
> - Keywords
> - Names with -
> - types names

```
SELECT [Attendee No], [Tracking Activity],[Tracking Date/Time],
CASE WHEN [Tracking Activity] IN ( 'Run', 'Walk', 'Jog', 'Gym') THEN 'Physical'
     ELSE 'NOT Physical' END AS [Activity Type]
FROM Tracker
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL CASE syntax to achieve it.

See SQL CASE on [W3SCHOOLS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)

Modify your SQL to something like the following and it should do the trick.

**SQL**

```
SELECT Attendance_No, Tracking_date,
CASE 
   WHEN Tracking_activity = 'Run' THEN 'Physical'
   WHEN Tracking_ctivity = 'Walk' THEN 'Physical'
   WHEN Tracking_ctivity = 'Jog' THEN 'Physical'
   WHEN Tracking_ctivity = 'Gym' THEN 'Physical'
   ELSE `Other`
END AS 'Activity-type'
FROM Tracker
```

Answer (score 0):

I started off with the case statement but what im getting blanks when the Tracking Activity is not in the list. I need ALL the activity type to say "Physical" if the attendee has  'Run', 'Walk', 'Jog', 'Gym' at anytime in the Attendee_No